# Is it possible to bind an activities to this service which works on background thread and always running?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

It's my first question on SO, I hope this question won't be bad.

I have a service, it starts working when user launchs an app and works until user will kill it via task killer or turn off his device.

This service has a background thread which does some work with data. I need to bind activities (from activities, not by service) and sometimes (1-2 times per 30 seconds) send data to binded activities.

Structure of my service:

```
public class myserv extends Service {
  public static boolean started=false;
  public class workwithdata extends Thread {
    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
      super.start();
      //.. Not important.
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (running) return;
      while (true) {
        if(condition) mythread.sleep(30000);
        else {
          Object data = recieveMyData();
          if (!data.isEmpty()) {
            //.. Some work with recieved data, not important.
            sendDataToBindedActivities(data); //This is what I need.
          }
          mythread.sleep(10000);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.started=true;
    mythread = new workwithdata();
    mythread.start();
  }
}
```

Well, I found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352244/revision-2-how-to-pass-data-from-a-background-service-thread-to-some-other-acti) but my problem has a little differences: I don't need to send any data to the service, I need just send some data to all binded activities (which service doesn't know at all).

Structure for which I'm looking for:

```
public class myact extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bun) {
    super.onCreate(bun);
    if(!myserv.started) {
      Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myserv.class);
      getApplicationContext().startService(service);
    }
    bindToService(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onRecievedData(Object data) {
    //work with recieved data from service "myserv".
  }
}
```

I also tried to find some solutions in android documentation but I didn't find what I need.

So, main question is: **is it possible to work with communications from service to activities?**. If no: **What should I use for this purpose?** If yes, just, sorry, can I ask for some code or class names, because I tried to find and didn't...

Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

Comment: so what exactly you want is sending some data to all the binded activities through your service??

Comment: @sachy yep. And service shouldn't know anything about activities.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA only to activities from my app.

Comment: So, I need to pass data (String) from service to binded activities and.. it's all. And this service always running (it doesn't have to start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [RemoteCallbackList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RemoteCallbackList.html)

When your clients bind to the service, you will need to register them using `RemoteCallbackList.register()`.

When you want to send data to the bound clients, you do something like this:

```
int count = callbackList.beginBroadcast();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    try {
        IMyServiceCallback client = callbackList.getBroadcastItem(i);
        client.onRecievedData(theData); // Here you callback the bound client's method
                                  //  onRecievedData() and pass "theData" back
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // We can safely ignore this exception. The RemoteCallbackList will take care
        //  of removing the dead object for us.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Not much we can do here except log it
        Log.e("while calling back remote client", e);
    }
}
callbackList.finishBroadcast();
```

An example can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.html) It is kinda complicated, but maybe you don't need everything this offers. In any case, have a look.

Comment: Is this possible to deny to bind not app's activities to my service?

Comment: Yes. You can prevent other application's access to your service using <android:export="false"> in the <service> tag in the manifest.

Comment: I've implemented it via `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and a few handlers. Is it bad? (I don't know but it works normally)

Comment: You can also do it that way. As long as your data isn't too big and it can easily be stored in SharedPreferences (ie: just simple primitives). Also, be aware that this gets complicated if your service is remote and runs in another process.

Comment: Yes, it runs on another process. But I made a few handlers with which it works normally.

Comment: I can only tell you that in some Android versions (especially 2.3), writing preferences in one process and reading them from another is **not** reliable. It should work better as of 3.x if you make sure to specify `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` when calling `getSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: Yes, in 2.2 it should work even without specifying `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` because that is the default behaviour. But, if you don't specify `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` then it will **not** work in later versions, unless you are targeting 2.2 or less with     <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="integer"/>