# Service not Starting from AsyncTask

Tags: service, android-asynctask

I tried to start my service from  AsyncTask but cannot see that its starting.

Hope you can see my errors.

here my code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //starts service number activite
    Intent i = new Intent(context, DownloadService.class);
    i.putExtra("url", "www.google.com");
    i.putExtra("receiver", new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
    context.startService(i);
```

here is my service

```
public class DownloadService extends Service{
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {  
        String urlLink = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        // some body
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        //publishing progress
        data.putString("key",getActivityUrl() );
        receiver.send(1,data);
    }

    ResultReceiver resultReceiver;

    public int onStart(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onHandleIntent( intent)
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

     public String getActivityUrl() {.....}
```

and my manifest file:

```
<service android:name="connection.DownloadService">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="connection.DownloadService">
    </action>        
</intent-filter>
```